# Setting field name if different from struct's XMLName

Tags: xml, go, wsdl

With a set of types generated by [gowsdl](https://github.com/hooklift/gowsdl) based on the [NetSuite SuiteTalk web service definition](http://www.netsuite.com/portal/developers/resources/suitetalk-documentation.shtml):

```
<complexType name="TokenPassportSignature">
   <simpleContent>
       <extension base="xsd:string">
          <attribute name="algorithm" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
       </extension>
    </simpleContent>
 </complexType>
 <complexType name="TokenPassport">
    <sequence>
       <element name="account" type="xsd:string"/>
       <element name="consumerKey" type="xsd:string"/>
       <element name="token" type="xsd:string"/>
       <element name="nonce" type="xsd:string"/>
       <element name="timestamp" type="xsd:long"/>
       <element name="signature" type="platformCore:TokenPassportSignature"/>
    </sequence>
</complexType>
```

It has created the following types:

```
type TokenPassportSignature struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"urn:core_2018_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com TokenPassportSignature"`
    Value string
    Algorithm string `xml:"algorithm,attr,omitempty"`
}

type TokenPassport struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"urn:core_2018_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com TokenPassport"`
    Account string `xml:"account,omitempty"`
    ConsumerKey string `xml:"consumerKey,omitempty"`
    Token string `xml:"token,omitempty"`
    Nonce string `xml:"nonce,omitempty"`
    Timestamp int64 `xml:"timestamp,omitempty"`
    Signature *TokenPassportSignature `xml:"signature,omitempty"`
}
```

When I try to process it through the client, the XML encoding process doesn't like that the Signature field has a conflicting name.

> xml: name "signature" in tag of main.TokenPassport.Signature conflicts with name "TokenPassportSignature" in *main.TokenPassportSignature.XMLName

I've [extracted out the relevant bits into Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/6R1FI-5Jd3Q) to confirm that this is the encoder that is throwing the error. Based on the docs for [Marhsal](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Marshal) it seems that the field must match:

> If the XML name for a struct field is defined by both the field tag
>   and the struct's XMLName field, the names must match.

Any thoughts on how to proceed?

Comment: Depending on how the un/marshaled data should look, either remove the tag or the XMLName field or edit one of those two so that they match.

Comment: ... here's an [example](https://play.golang.org/p/5R74m44uKMp) (i'm not sure whether or not you need the namespace to be present so i've added it to the tag). Also note the `,chardata` tag option on the `Value` field, without it the marshaler will add an inner element to the signature element which is not something you want I assume.

Comment: Thanks @mkopriva that is useful. If you add that as an answer I'll flag it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, one might prefer to keep the name of the embedded structure `TokenPassportSignature` instead of the name `signature`. 
If the naming of the field, the line becomes:

```
Signature *TokenPassportSignature `xml:",omitempty"`
```

[Code adapted](https://play.golang.org/p/kLTfiFcwRcp)

Answer (score 0):

Unsure of what didn't work for you, but this worked for me, with recent versions of netsuite wsdl, and gowsdl:

```
nonce:=RandStringBytes(20)
timestamp:=strconv.FormatInt(time.Now().Unix(),10)    
baseString:= strings.Join([]string{account, consumer_key, token, nonce, timestamp}, "&")
secretString:= strings.Join([]string{consumer_secret, token_secret}, "&")
signature := HashHmacSha256(baseString, secretString)

tokenPassportSignature:= netsuite.TokenPassportSignature {
    Value: signature,
    Algorithm: "HMAC-SHA256",
}    
tokenPassport:= netsuite.TokenPassport {
    Account: account,
    ConsumerKey: consumer_key,
    Token: token,
    Nonce: nonce,
    Timestamp: time.Now().Unix(),
    Signature: &tokenPassportSignature,
}
client := soap.NewClient("https://12345-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/NetSuitePort_2022_1")
client.AddHeader(tokenPassport)
```

using

```
type TokenPassportSignature struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"signature"`
    Value string `xml:",chardata" json:"-,"`
    Algorithm string `xml:"algorithm,attr,omitempty" json:"algorithm,omitempty"`
}
type TokenPassport struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"tokenPassport"`
    Account string `xml:"account,omitempty" json:"account,omitempty"`
    ConsumerKey string `xml:"consumerKey,omitempty" json:"consumerKey,omitempty"`
    Token string `xml:"token,omitempty" json:"token,omitempty"`
    Nonce string `xml:"nonce,omitempty" json:"nonce,omitempty"`
    Timestamp int64 `xml:"timestamp,omitempty" json:"timestamp,omitempty"`
    Signature *TokenPassportSignature `xml:"signature,omitempty" json:"signature,omitempty"`
}
```

A full proof of concept: https://github.com/mk-j/go-netsuite-soap